# Issue Management Advice for SharePoint Beginner-Archiving updates?

Tags: 2010, list

I've been tasked with creating a SharePoint site to manage issues. I'm imagining a list and view where I'll be able to create an "issue" and monitor progress resolving that issue via status updates and archival history.

For example, let's a Green Honda Civic comes in needing a tire change, an oil change, and a wash. I'd put it the "Green Honda Civic" as the issue with a description and date. On day one, the tires are changed. The a status update is added to the issue explaining such.

The next day the oil is changed - now here is where I'm stuck on. I'd like to add a status update that the "oil is changed" but it should NOT overwrite the tire change update. However, in a view for management, it should only display the latest oil change update - ostensibly at least. The previous tire change should be "archived" away- available if someone wants to investigate, but hidden for a the quick overview.

Any suggestions to achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by adding an Issues Tracking list.

1. Open sharepoint site
2. Click Site Actions, More Options
3. Select Issues Tracking and Click Create button

Once the list is created, you can go to list settings and change the Comments column -> Append changes = Yes

This will store a new version of the comment each time you save the item.

**Ideal Approach**

1. Use the same issues list
2. For each action you should create a new item and assign it to respective person

   - For example tire change should be assigned to PersonA
   - Oil change should be assigned to PersonB
3. Create a view which group by title (This should be unique for each case)
4. Manager can expand the group and see what is the status/progress of each item